# Remove Project Server Completely from SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, content-database, project-server

My SharePoint 2016 environment have MS Project Server.

I want to remove MS project Server from my environment completely and cleanly. I want to remove its database schema, service application, services  and all other traces from SharePoint farm.

Currently, I have deleted service application and stopped service. But I want to clear content database with MS project tables e.g. `MSP_ASSIGNMENT_BASELINES`, `MSP_PROJ_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUES`, etc.

I read in many sites that it is not possible to remove MS project completely. Is there any manual way to clean SharePoint content database.

Can I delete tables directly from database?

Answer (score 0):

It is never recommended to delete the table directly from the database in SharePoint.

It cannot be uninstalled from the farm. If you want to remove Project Server functionality, you can turn off the Project Application Service and delete the Project Server 2013 Service Application.

Comment: Thanks Julie.. Yeah,  this is the only way to stop Project Server in SharePoint. Microsoft should do something to remove Project Server from SP environment if you don't need it. It is not good to keep seeing these tables in SP content database and keep them migrating from one version to another without using them.